# How to map an Observable with values from another observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular-observable

I obtain my Ofertas here

```
getOfertasByYear(year:number): Observable<Oferta[]> {
return this.http.get<Oferta[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas/year/${year}`)
  .pipe(
    map(ofertas=>
      ofertas.map(oferta=>({
        ...oferta,
        añoPresentada:new Date(oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum).getFullYear(),
        organismoId:¿¿¿???
      }) as Oferta)
      ),
    tap(data => console.log('OfertasService-getOfertasByYear(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

But I need to calculate his organismoId and that is here

```
getOrganismoDeOferta(ofertaId:string): Observable<Organismo> {
return this.http.get<Organismo>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/organismos/oferta/${ofertaId}`)
  .pipe(
    tap(//data=>console.log('OfertasService-getOrganismos(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

And I don't know how to pass the result of this Observable to te mapped property

```
getOfertasByYear(year:number): Observable<Oferta[]> {
return this.http.get<Oferta[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas/year/${year}`)
  .pipe(
    map(ofertas=>
      ofertas.map(oferta=>({
        ...oferta,
        añoPresentada:new Date(oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum).getFullYear(),
        organismoId:this.getOrganismoDeOferta(oferta.id).subscribe(data=>{
          ¿¿¿¿??????
        })
      }) as Oferta)
      ),
    tap(data => console.log('OfertasService-getOfertasByYear(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
 }
```

I subscribe to it but I don't know how to make the assignment

I have tried to obtain all Ofertas and All Concursos but neither

```
ofertas$ = this.dataService.getOfertas();
concursos$ = this.dataService.getConcursos();

ofertasConOrganismos$ = forkJoin([
 this.ofertas$,
 this.concursos$
])
.pipe(
  map(([ofertas, concursos]) =>
    ofertas.map(oferta => ({
      ...oferta,
      organismoId: concursos.find(c => c.id ==                oferta.concursoId).organismoId
    }) as Oferta))
);
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'organismoId')
```

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a plain `map` and then calling `.subscribe()`, you can use a "[Higher-Order Mapping Operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" to handle the inner subscription for you. In this case, let's use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

The idea is to return an observable inside `switchMap` that emits the data you need.  Since you need to make multiple calls, we can leverage some help from [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

With `forkJoin` you pass in an array of observables, and it will emit an array of the results.  So here below we map the array of `Oferta` to an array of observables that will each emit the `Oferta` with the `organismoId` appended:

```js
getOfertasByYear(year: number): Observable<Oferta[]> {
    return this.http.get<Oferta[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas/year/${year}`).pipe(
        switchMap(ofertas => forkJoin(
            ofertas.map(oferta => this.appendOrganismo(oferta))
        )),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

Nothing too fancy for the definition of `appendOrganismo()`; we just make the http call, then map the result to the desired shape:

```js
private appendOrganismo(oferta: Oferta) {
    return this.getOrganismoDeOferta(oferta.id).pipe(
        map(organismo => ({
            ...oferta,
            añoPresentada: new Date(oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum).getFullYear(),
            organismoId: organismo.id
        }))
    );
}
```

Comment: @BizzBob thanks for your great explanation but Now I have an error in appendOrganismo() in the line organismoId:organismo.id TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id'). I don't understand it you call to getOrganismoDeOferta but never subscribe to te data returned?